# How do I get a RateLimitStatus object in Twitter4j?

Tags: java, api, twitter, twitter4j

I'm trying to make a method `public void limit()` that checks the rate limit and sleeps however long it is until the reset if it is being rate limited. I cannot, however, figure out how to make a RateLimitStatus. I have tried:
`RateLimitStatus status = twitter.getRateLimitStatus();`
but it doesn't actually return a RateLimitStatus... Quite frankly, I'm not sure what the point of that is. Anyway, if anyone is aware of how to get a RateLimitStatus, their help would be much appreciated as currently my project is capable of crashing due to rate limits and I'd like to change this.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

The new Twitter API has a rate limit status *per* [resource “family”](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/application/rate_limit_status), so `twitter.getRateLimitStatus()` returns a mapping between families/endpoints and rate limit statuses, e.g.:

```
RateLimitStatus status = twitter.getRateLimitStatus().get("/users/search");

// Better: specify the family
RateLimitStatus status2 = twitter.getRateLimitStatus("users").get("/users/search");
```

So, you could write a method `public void limit(String endpoint)`, which would check the proper rate limit status.

```
public void limit(String endpoint) {
  String family = endpoint.split("/", 3)[1];
  RateLimitStatus status = twitter.getRateLimitStatus(family).get(endpoint);
  // do what you want…
}
```

You’ll then call it with `.limit("/users/search")`.

Comment: Do rates for /search/tweets apply to the streaming api?

Answer (score 6):

```
Map<String ,RateLimitStatus> rateLimitStatus = twitter.getRateLimitStatus();
for (String endpoint : rateLimitStatus.keySet()) {
    RateLimitStatus status = rateLimitStatus.get(endpoint);
    System.out.println("Endpoint: " + endpoint);
    System.out.println(" Limit: " + status.getLimit());
    System.out.println(" Remaining: " + status.getRemaining());
    System.out.println(" ResetTimeInSeconds: " + status.getResetTimeInSeconds());
    System.out.println(" SecondsUntilReset: " + status.getSecondsUntilReset());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twitter API also allows for:

```
Log.d("TwitterActivity", "Limit:" + mTwitter.getFavorites().getRateLimitStatus().getLimit());
```

Where:

- mTwitter is your Twitter object
- getFavorites() can be replaced by any other function that Twitter4j provides for the Twitter object
- getLimit() is but one of the various options you can choose

You can check like so:

```
if(mTwitter.getFavorites().getRateLimitStatus().getLimit() <= 0){
    //do something
}
```